# How can I filter a dictionary and store the values in a list?

Tags: python, yaml

I want to search for similar values in a dictionary and store the value in a list.
This is a little piece of the dictionary Load from yaml:

```py
global_var:
  rt_id: 12345
var_rtr_a:
  subnet: 10.10.1.0/28
var_rtr_b:
  subnet: 10.10.2.0/28
```

I tried it with this code

```
key = ['subnet']
values = list(map(mydictionray.get, keys)
# Output: [none]
```

I understand why the output is `None`, because the key is not correct.
But how can I define the correct key ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a dict of dicts.

Go for a recursive solution:

```
def recursive_key_search(key, lookup):
    if isinstance(lookup, dict):
        for _key in lookup.keys():
            if _key == key:
                output.append(lookup[key])
            recursive_key_search(key, lookup[_key])
```

Sample use:

```py
test_dict = {
    'a': 'b',
    'c': {'d': 'e'}
}

output = []

recursive_key_search('d', test_dict)

print(output)
# >>> ['e']
```

Comment: i tested your code. the problem is, with my dict. the output have 27 emty list.. and two list with the subnets...

Comment: You can append only `if lookup[key] is not None` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The way your data is formatted has it with a dictionary inside of a dictionary.  When you look for `subnet`, you're only looking at the first layer of dictionaries, and not the second where subnet belongs.

One way of amending this that I can think of would be to iterate through the exterior values of the dictionary, and then search for subnet inside of those:

```
def search_dict(data):
     output = []
     for k in data:
          try:
               output.append(data[k]['subnet'])
     return output
```

This will correctly get every subnet from the dictionary and output it to a list.

```
Output:
['10.10.1.0/28', '10.10.1.0/28']
```